# CSS Space Between Buttons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, button

I'm trying to have an empty space between two buttons in jQuery Mobile.  The layout in reality looks like this:

```
Button 1      Button 2 (Hidden w/ display: none)        Button 3
```

And on my page it looks like this:

```
Button 1      Button 3
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Button 1                            Button 3
```

without deleting the hidden 2nd button, because that button will be displayed as a back button to go back to search results.  So, if there are search results, it should look like it does at the top of the page, except with display: none being gone.

I've tried float: right on the 3rd button, but that gives me this:

```
               Button 3              Button 1
```

Any CSS experts who know how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code? And why have you only accepted 1 of your 9 questions? You need to accept more answers.

Comment: Use `visibility: hidden` so the element will take it's place, but will be invisible.

Comment: Because by the time anyone gets back to me, my problem has already been solved by me tinkering with other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`.

Comment: If you wanted to fade it out using jQuery, use `animate({ opacity:0 }, 500);`